# How can I check if a user, that has been pass in parameters to bash script, really exists?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have simple bash script, that shows information about user

```
#!/bin/bash

grep home /etc/passwd | grep $1
```

If I pass to script incorrect name, for example, ./script_find_users.sh bbbbbbbbbbbbb

the script gives nothing in output, but I want at least some simple message

```
echo "User does't exists"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return status:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! grep home /etc/passwd | grep -- "$1"; then
  echo User "$1" does not have an entry in /etc/passwd >&2
fi
```